# Fetch html content from different domain which is injectedt by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, selenium, curl

It is possible to fetch html content from another domain in php via "file_get_contents" or cURL e.g. http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download .
But how can i fetch it when DOM elements are injected via JavaScript?

And if that is not possible on the server level, although i have no experience in Selenium, and this is a guess: can i somehow use Selenium (+RC?) on my local machine and access webpage from the third party domain?

-i should add that the elements seem to be added onload and not bounded to any triggers.

Comment: tampermonkey or greasemonkey would allow you to run your own code on any site.

Comment: @dandavis, i didn't thought of greasemonkey. Well actually i need some script that goes automatically through a range of pages and read some data, stores and does stuff with them. So with a greasemonkey script i still have to call the pages and do the storing manually but it would definitely be way faster and easier.

Comment: you can call the pages with a greasemonkey script too. i usually use an array of URL, localStorage for a cursor, an iframe to inkoke the url/workdload userscript, and window.postMessage to fire the "load the next url" part...

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it on the server-side, then simply

```
$contents = file_get_contents('url to page');
echo $contents;
```

If you wanna do it on the client-side

```
 $.ajax({
    'url' : 'URL HERE',
    'type' : 'GET',
    'success' : function(data) {              
       $("#contents").html(data);
    }
});
```

Note: The client-side will only work if the the appropriate access control origin headers are sent (most websites don't allow them)

Comment: The client side code can only work if appropriate CORS headers are set since according to the OP they come from *another domain*.

Comment: @Ali, as i tried to say, the problem is that i get the static html, but all the elements that are inserted during the onload which are visible to the browser, are not fetched by php.